# Pyodbc SQL Server connection doesn't work, when run as a windows service

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, pyodbc

I use the following code, to create connection to SQL Server database. When I just run my flask application, it works fine.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}',
                      server='my_user',
                      database='my_db',
                      username='my_username',
                      password='pass',
                      trusted_connection='yes'
                      )
```

But now I've created Windows service, using nssm tool. The service just runs .bat file, that starts my service.

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
[SQL Server]Login failed for user \'WORKGROUP\\my_user$\'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect);
[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database 
"my_db" requested by the login.
The login failed. (4060); [28000] [Microsoft]
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0);
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Run service with administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

The answer's in the error message! These things can be a challenge if you're not familiar with service accounts and SQL Server. If you can't open the database specified in the login, it's usually one of these things:

1. Database name specified in the connection string does not exist.
2. There is no user specified in the database to map onto the login you're using.
3. You're running the application (in this case, your service) under a different Windows service account to the one that the code was previously developed under, and *that* (ie: the Windows Service Account) account does not have a login and/or a user defined in SQL Server, either at the server level for the login, or at the database level if the login exists.

Simplest solution would be to record what Windows account your service is running under, and then check that same account exists as a login, in the SQL Server your service is trying to connect to. If it doesn't, that's your problem, and you just need to create the login, and make sure it has an associated user in the database (a login only gets you into the server, not the databases).
However, if the login does exist, check that a) the database exists and b) (IMPORTANT!) a user exists in that database that maps onto to the service account login.

As an aside, the previous answer about running the service with an account that has Administrator privileges is unlikely to work, unless you're using an old version of SQL Server. The automatic ability for Windows sysadmins to have automatic rights to a database server and its data was removed long ago, so using a Windows Administrator account will either not work, or will not be future proof if it does.

Let me know if this doesn't fix it.